# Keep PivotTable report filter after data refresh

Tags: sql-server, excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

I have a PivotTable (actually it is five PivotTables, each on its own separate sheet) that is created from a query of an outside database. Each of the PivotTables represents a day (i.e. Today, Tomorrow, Today+2, Today+3, and Today+4). For the report filter for the first two, we use a date range filter of today and tomorrow which automatically filters the data and allows it to roll over. We created custom date ranges for the other three days, but upon every external data refresh we have to go into each sheet and reselect the report filter from all to the specified time frame. This data rolls over every day so we can see the lineup for the next 96 hours out.

Is there a way to either keep the PivotTable report filter criteria (VBA and macros are both acceptable, although we are also fairly new to both)?

Or is there some super secret way to extend the report filter from just today and tomorrow to a time range (48 hours, 96 hours) instead of next month?

I need the days to be separated, so next week will not work because all the days will populate on one page.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a real example it's hard to tell, but how about changing the *query* to a *relative* date index, i.e. something like

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('day', GETDATE(), report_dt) AS days_from_today FROM reporting_table
```

And then set your report filters on this relative date index (`days_from_today = 1` for tomorrow, etc)?  You can always create another Excel column in the report `=TODAY() + days_from_today` to get your absolute date back.  (Assuming you are just dealing with one time zone for reporting purposes.)

I.e., instead of rolling filters, keep the filters on constant indices, and let the indices cover a rolling date range.  I'm not sure Excel is smart enough to do the rolling filters thing.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately we are a logistics company who delivers country wide and do work with all time zones. Also I can not post the actual spreadsheet due to the sensitive nature of the information. I can come up with a mock sheet that has the formulas and fake company info without the query, but not sure it would compute correctly. I do thank you again for the suggestion, I will run it by my co-woker (this is a collaboration between us as he runs the server side of the query) and see if this is a viable option and if we could use a single time zone for this purpose.Thanks

Comment: @JuStin OK, don't get too hung up on the time zone issue.  In SQL Server there is a `datetime` and also a `date` data type.  Your question was not specific as to which type the query returns.  If it is just a `date` data type then the approach outlined above should be fine.  Otherwise you might need to replace `report_dt` with `CONVERT(date, report_dt)` and just note that the output is specific to whatever locale your data warehouse uses (e.g., GMT). Also, it is a good practice to include the "fake" data example as you mentioned.